# Schizoid twin brothers

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

There are two identical twin brothers.

- The first one is honest, but he lies in his schizophrenic situations.
- The second one is well-known liar, but he tells the truth when he gets one of his pathologic seizures .

What kind of yes-no questions should you ask anyone of them to detect whether he is in his normal or in his irregular state?

Comment: There is [a simpler way](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0327.html) to determine if they tell the truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do you always speak the truth when you are crazy?

"yes" indicates that they are currently crazy

---

I just realised that the opposite also works and might be simpler

> do you lie on purpose?

"yes" indicates that they are currently crazy

Comment: there is a simpler and shorter question :D

Comment: I edited it, it's the same question but simpler. dunno how to make it more simple.

Comment: you can ... "are you in your pathologic situation ?"

Comment: but this answer is accepted thu

Comment: @Abidare001 "are you in your pathological situation" would always be answered no by the honest twin and yes by the liar. It's a useful question,  but not what is asked for here.

Comment: yes right ... i mixed up things